# How do I style two different <ul> tags in HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a 'ul' tag that already styles something else. I need to create another 'ul' tag to stylize something else in my HTML page.

This is the first `ul` style:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: arial;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

I need to style another `ul` where I create a list of items. I want the default CSS settings for the `ul` tags, but I don't know how to make that work.

Here is the HTML code for the `ul` list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

What code will make the above `ul` tag go back to the default CSS settings?

Answer (score 4):

Better assign a class for the first `ul` and add styles for that CSS class, then other `ul` in the page will not get affected.

```css
.first-ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="first-ul">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the two  inside of a div and style using accordingly.

simple markup

```
<div class="somediv">
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

simple css

```
.somediv ul:first-child {
    background: blue
}

.somediv ul:nth-child(2) {
    background: red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different class names (one common and one different name) to the UL and give as many properties as you wish.

```css
.common{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: arial;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
}

.red
{
color:red;
}

.green
{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="common red">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="common green">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="first">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="scnd">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

add like this in your stylesheet

```
.first ul
{
    Your style here
}
.scnd ul
{
    Your style here
}
```